# Automate a process in QGIS using graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have tasks that I need to automate:

1. Dissolve line features by attribute - (Dissolve tool)
2. Split the dissolved layer into single parts - (Multipart to singleparts tool)
3. Extract different layers based on an attribute(values are integers e.g. from 1 to 6) - (Split vector layer tool) - here the result is many layers depending on unique attributes. The results are saved in a directory(folder).
4. Intersect one extracted layer with another layer - (Split line with lines). Here only two layers can be intersected. there is a pattern to intersect for example where attribute = 1, then intersect with layer whose attribute =2. Therefore only an increment of 1
5. Merge the resulting layers.

As input I have a stream network that is quite segmented. This process ensures that I have the correct number of segments based on my requirements.

I am able to set up the tools until number 3. I have set up the input parameters as the layer and the field to dissolve. The result of number 3 is many different layers that are stored in an output directory. I have no clue on how to access the output directory and set up the Intersection (number 4).